# Is google ads script support GmailApp.sendmail ....?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, sendmail

I am trying to sending mail through ads script using GmailApp.sendmail but getting below error

ReferenceError: "GmailApp" is not defined.

Help me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

### Google Ads does not seem to support `GmailApp`, but it supports [`MailApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail)

The [reference](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/whats-new) shows you under "Script Services" which apps are supported.

Comment: i have used mailapp but my mails are getting blocked ...any solution for this

Comment: Using Apps Script directly instead of Ads Scripts?